# CakePHP Associations, Containable, and Threaded

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-model

Hi I've got a couple of questions regarding associations and how they play in cases
of complex *find()* calls.

- If I've got a model **Post** and a model **Comment** with the latter having a **parent_id** field
  and I want to fetch a post with its associated comments threaded, do I simply perform a
  **find('threaded', ...)** on **Post** itself or will this result in an error because **Post** doesn't
  have a **parent_id**? I am particularly concerned about a *Containable + Threaded find*. (the 
  example I give here is a simplified version of what I actually need to implement)
- What is the significance of **Association Names**? Does **Containable** work on association names
  or model names? *(the reason I want to know this is because I'm trying to implement polymorphic models by having condition-specific model associations, often having multiple associations to the same model)*

Comment: Quoting from CakePHP Cook Book: The contain method’s first argument accepts the name, or an array of names, of the **models** to keep in the find operation.

So I guess that partly answers the second half of my question; unless  the cook-book was loosely worded, which I highly doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I *think* that containable would not support threaded finds on the contained models. EG you might have a `post_id` column in your `comments` table, and do something like:

  $this->Comment->find('threaded', array(
      'conditions' => array(
          'post_id' => 5)));
- Although the book may say that Containable uses the model name, I have regularly used the association name in Containable when I have multiple joins between the same models. For simple projects, the model name is usually the same as the association name, so that may be why the book says that.

Comment: Got a similar answer here as well - http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/d149e6617d773ea9

Thanks :)

Comment: No problem -- would be cool to have threaded contained models